# Are they similar, "Their mom is getting them excited with the gifts" and "The gifts are making them excited"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

It seems that not many people know why sometimes we say "**get something + adjective**" and "**make something + adjective**".

It seems noone knows general pattern of how to use  "**get something + adjective**" and "**make something + adjective**".

But, I feel like "**get**" is often used in the pattern "**somebody + get + somebody/something + adjective**" and "**make**" is often used in the pattern "**something + make + somebody + adjective**" or "**somebody + make + something + adjective**".

For example,

**He got his fingers caught in the door.** ([from the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get))

**Don’t get the children too excited.** ([from the dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get))

**The news made him very happy.** ([from the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1?q=make))

**She made her objections clear.** ([from the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1?q=make))

Are they similar, "**Their mom is getting them excited with the gifts**" and "**The gifts are making them excited**"?

It is strange to say "**Their mom is making them excited with the gifts**" and "**The gifts are getting them excited**", isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - have the children received the gifts yet, or not? Neither sentence seems very idiomatic to me. You could say "Their mom is getting them excited _about_ the gifts (that they will have tomorrow)." When they have received them, it would be more natural to say "They are excited about the gifts" than "The gifts are making them excited."

Comment: @KateBunting, that is what I am asking, why do we say "**the news is making them happy**", but we can't say "**The gifts are making them excited**". It seems like using "**make or get**" is all dependent on the adjectives that we chose.

Comment: I didn't say that we _couldn't_ say 'The gifts are making them excited", just that it would be more usual to say it the other way round. I think that **to get someone excited** means to actively encourage them to become excited, so only a person can do that. (Forget about 'getting your fingers trapped' - that's a different use of 'get'.)